# how to change expression DateTime in EFCore

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core

i use EFCore to search DB.

When TValue == DateTime,it not run.

```
        /// <summary>
        /// 大于或等于
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="propertyName"></param>
        /// <param name="value"></param>
        public void GreaterThanOrEqual<TValue>(string propertyName, TValue value)
        {
            var prop = type.GetProperty(propertyName);
            Expression left = Expression.Property(param, prop);
            Expression right = Expression.Constant(value, prop.PropertyType);
            Expression result = Expression.GreaterThanOrEqual(left, right);
            filter = Expression.And(filter, result);
        }
```

I see the cosole ,the sql is

```
 SELECT COUNT(*)
      FROM [tOrganization] AS [item]
      WHERE (1 & CASE
          WHEN [item].[CreateTime] >= '2013-02-26T00:00:00.0000000'
          THEN CAST(1 AS BIT) ELSE CAST(0 AS BIT)
      END) = 1
```

but the column named CreateTime is datetime ,not datetime2.

how can i do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the db entity property need to add [Column(TypeName = "datetime")] attribute.
and the db entity property like  money,decimal(18,15) ,need add this attribute too.